# Is JDBC performance limited by the Number of Sockets you have available on your hardware?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, sockets, jdbc

So I have a single threaded Java program that is reading and writing from a mysql database and it runs perfectly fine.

But when I try to parallelize the work by using two or more threads, the code starts running considerably slower(25 seconds for a batch update of a 100K, compared to 5 seconds for the single threaded code).

Now when I look at the System Information box in Java Flight Recorder, it says the following:

```
 Number of Sockets = 1.
```

So does this mean that only one thread at any given time can be reading or writing to the database, as this will be going through the one and only socket? So the performance is being killed by threads acquiring and releasing a lock for that one socket...

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: "Number of Sockets" probably refers to the number of CPU sockets, not to the number of network sockets. As it stands, this is not really answerable, as for all we know you might be handling the concurrency wrong, introducing additional overhead and delays.